# Error with PDO and dynamic limit

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, limit

Just working through some legacy code updating to PDO, I keep getting an error with the following code:

```
$p = $productsperpage*($currentpage-1);
$productsperpage = 1;

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` LIMIT :start,:results");
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $p, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':results', $productperpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

The problem seems to be with the limit using bound parameters, please can anyone help with getting this working?

The error :

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''1'' at line 2 in /test/category.php on line 163

Thanks

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'' at line 2 in /test/category.php on line 163

Comment: Hi, sorry forgot to mention I had tried casting to int but I get the following error when I do: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /Applications/AMPPS/www/shellstore/category.php:163 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /test/category.php on line 163

Comment: replace :start,:results with static values and check once...